# Using a variable in a raw JSON string in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and i have been having a challenge using a variable in a raw JSON string.

The string below works fine;

```
const std::string rawJSON = R"({"PID":14112,"size":172,"daddr":"239.255.255.250","saddr":"192.168.1.64","dport":1900,"sport":49807})";
```

But i have the json object in between the brackets as a variable. How can i use the variable in this scenario? i.e

```
const std::string rawJson = R"(variable)";
```

This is what i have tried so far but i am getting an error;
The "variable" holds the json object. This a sample code;

```
#include "json/json.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
const std::string rawJson = R"(variable)";
const auto rawJsonLength = static_cast<int>(rawJson.length());
constexpr bool shouldUseOldWay = false;
JSONCPP_STRING err;
Json::Value root;

if (shouldUseOldWay) {
    Json::Reader reader;
    reader.parse(rawJson, root);
}
else {
    Json::CharReaderBuilder builder;
    const std::unique_ptr<Json::CharReader> reader(builder.newCharReader());
    if (!reader->parse(rawJson.c_str(), rawJson.c_str() + rawJsonLength, &root,
        &err)) {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
const std::string pid= root["PID"].asString();
const int size= root["size"].asInt();

std::cout << pid << std::endl;
std::cout << size<< std::endl;
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Comment: If you already have the entire JSON in a string variable, why do you need an extra "raw string"? It seems like you could just use `variable` directly?

Comment: What you are asking is called *string interpolation* it's supported by many languages but not C++. The closest alternative in C++ is the `ostringstream` class. Boost [format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) might also be worth a look.

Comment: *"i am getting an error"* - what error? Please read about [mre] and [edit]  your question accordingly

Comment: @UnholySheep i have edited the code accordingly

Comment: Hi, I think there's a variable in your program confusingly called `variable` and that contains values for `PID` and `size` so when the string `"(variable)"` is processed it is interpreted as a reference to the variable `variable` and the appropriate values returned.

Comment: @Persixty yes sure the variable "variable" is actually a string like this {"PID":14112,"size":172}

Comment: I got it to work guys, there was an error in my json object. The above code now works. Thank you for your support

Comment: @robkims I think you should add that to the example to make it clear what you're trying to achieve. Which JSON library are you using? You shouldn't expect the library to be able to find names in your code to substitute for values in a string. C++ doesn't work like that. There's no C++ native way of (say) performing `int x=7; int y=eval("x");` and expecting y to be assigned the value '`7`.

Answer (score -1):

Use Simple Macro to convert your datatype name to str.have look at this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> 
#include <string>
#define JSON_UTILITIES(VAR) #VAR

int main () {
 int key = 0;
 std::stringstream ss;
 ss << JSON_UTILITIES(key) << ":" << key;
 std::cout <<"{ "<< ss.str () << " }"; 
 system ("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be at all what OP is asking for